# Delphi: Путь до папки AppData

Tags: delphi

Как получить полный путь до папки AppData в Delphi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function GetDOSEnvVar(const VarName: string): string;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    i := GetEnvironmentVariable(PChar(VarName), nil, 0);
    if i > 0 then
    begin
      SetLength(Result, i);
      GetEnvironmentVariable(Pchar(VarName), PChar(Result), i);
    end;
  except
    Result := '';
  end;
end;

GetDOSEnvVar('AppData');
```

Копипаст) :)